# How do I get all posts that belong to a post type? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models:

```
class PostType < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders, :history]

  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :post

  validates :name, presence: true

end
```

And

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders, :history]

  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :user

  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, join_table: 'tags_posts', :dependent => :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, join_table: 'categories_posts', :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true

  before_save :set_default_post_type

  ...

  private

  def set_default_post_type
    if self.post_type_id == nil
      post_type_object = PostType.find_by(name: 'post')
      self.post_type_id = post_type_object.id
    end
  end

end
```

As you can see Post belongs to blog, and post type belongs to both blog and post. Posts, when created are created with a default post type of 1 (that particular code will be cleaned up)

So my question is, how do I set up the relation such that I can do:

```
PostType.find(1).posts.all
```

Right now I can do `Blog.find(1).posts.all` because Blog has many posts and post belong to blog, where as post has one post_type and post_types can belong to many posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Post.where('post_types.id = ?', some_id).joins(:post_types)
```

You can create a method in PostType:

```
def posts
  Post.where('post_types.id = ?', id).joins(:post_types)
end
```

Comment: [`references`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references) should used with [`includes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes)

Comment: I feel like this is wrong. Like I should be able to do this through relationships. See Blogs has many posts where post belongs to blog. So I can do `Blogs.find(x).posts.all` and Post types belong to post as a post can only have on post type. So i should be able to do something like `PostType.find(x).posts.all` no? why am I having to do a `.where` and a `.references`? (it works by the way ... but .... still.

Comment: there is no relation for that table structure, if you want something like PostType has_many/has_and_belongs_to_many Posts you will need Post with `post_type_id` or a join table `posts_post_types` respectively.

Comment: what you can do is change the table structure to use single table inheritance(STI), and add an index. would you be interested in that option?